# Loading of textfile resource in Visual Studio loads more than it should

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, resources

As seen in various other posts, I have added a few text files as resources in a Visual Studio 2013 project in the following way: After right-clicking on the project and selecting Add -> Resources I added the following lines to the generated file `resource.h`:

```
#define MY_TEXTFILE 256
#define MY_CONFIG_FILE_RELEASE 4313
#define MY_CONFIG_FILE_DEV1 4314
#define MY_CONFIG_FILE_DEV2 4315
```

Then, I added the following lines to the `.rc` file:

```
MY_CONFIG_FILE_RELEASE MY_TEXTFILE "configFiles/releaseConfig.properties"
MY_CONFIG_FILE_DEV1 MY_TEXTFILE "configFiles/devConfig.properties"
MY_CONFIG_FILE_DEV2 MY_TEXTFILE "configFiles/dev2Config.properties"
```

The content of those files is just simply one line, e.g. for the `devConfig.properties` it would be

```
# DEV1 CONFIG
```

To test the loading mechanism, I use the following directly within `main`

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  const char* data = NULL;
  loadTextFileResource(MY_CONFIG_FILE_DEV1, data);

  return 0;
}
```

where the `loadTextFileResource` is the following:

```
bool loadTextFileResource(int inName, const char*& outData) {
  HMODULE _handle;
  GetModuleHandleEx(GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_FROM_ADDRESS |
    GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_UNCHANGED_REFCOUNT, (LPCTSTR)&someFunction, &_handle);
  if (_handle == NULL) return false;

  HRSRC _rc = FindResource(_handle, MAKEINTRESOURCE(inName), MAKEINTRESOURCE(MY_TEXTFILE));
  if (_rc == NULL) return false;

  HGLOBAL _rcData = LoadResource(_handle, _rc);
  if (_rcData == NULL) return false;

  LPVOID _rcDataLocked = LockResource(_rcData);
  if (_rcDataLocked == NULL) return false;

  DWORD _size = SizeofResource(_handle, _rc);
  if (_size == 0) return false;

  outData = static_cast<const char*>(_rcDataLocked);

  std::cout << "Loaded: " << outData << std::endl;

  return true;
}
```

The output of this little program is:

```
Loaded: # DEV1 CONFIG
P# DEV2 CONFIG

PADPADDINGXXPADDINGPADDINGXXPADDINGPADDINGXXPADDINGPADDINGXXPADDINGPADDINGXXPADD
INGPADDINGXXPADDINGPADDINGXXPADDINGPADDINGXXPADDINGPADDINGXXPADDINGPADDINGXXPADD
INGPADDINGXXPADDINGPADDINGXXPADDINGPADDINGXXPADDINGPADDINGXXPADDINGPADDINGXXPADD
INGPADDINGXXPADDINGPADDINGXXPADDINGPADDINGXXPADDINGPADDINGXXPADDINGPADDINGXXPADD
INGPADDINGXXPADDINGPADDINGXXPADDINGPADDINGXXPADDING
```

Note that the two lines in the beginning are the content of not only `MY_CONFIG_FILE_DEV1` but also `MY_CONFIG_FILE_DEV2` even though I only requested the former. The same happens when I request to load `MY_CONFIG_FILE_RELEASE` (i.e. all three files are loaded into `outData`). So it seems that somehow all "subsequent" resources are loaded together with the one I'm requesting. What is going on here exactly and why is my `loadTextFileResource` function not doing what I'm expecting, namely load only the content of the resource I'm requesting?

Also: What is the "P" doing in front of "#DEV2 CONFIG" (which is the content of the respective file)? Should I somehow clean the data that was loaded?

Note that this loading mechanism should also work if the project is compiled as a DLL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assume that the text file data is zero-terminated by assigning the pointer to the beginning of the resource to the `const char *`:

```
outData = static_cast<const char*>(_rcDataLocked);
```

Basically, you don't use the `size` at all. All you need is to construct the string (`std::string` or `std::wstring` depending on the encoding used by your original text files):

```
std::string result = { static_cast<const char *>(_rcDataLocked), size };
```

or

```
std::wstring result = { static_cast<const wchar_t *>(_rcDataLocked), size / sizeof(wchar_t) };
```

Comment: You are of course right - I was able to fix it, so thanks! The code you posted did not work for me though, I used memcopy to copy the data in a string.

Comment: Sorry, this code works on Visual Studio 2015, but might not work on VS 2013. The following must work: `std::string result(static_cast<const char *>(_rcDataLocked), size);`